# Change woocommerce-loop-product__title From H2 to H6

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to change the Woocommerce "woocommerce-loop-product__title" from a H2 to a H6 but I'm having some trouble locating the function.

Can anyone advise on the location in the plugin files or better yet how to override it in the themes functions.php file?

Thanks

Comment: As some themes make some changes to WooCommerce templates, function templates, **the Method 2 below works in Storefront theme**, but in other themes it will make a duplicated title. **So 1st you need to add in your question, the theme that you are using.** Then in your theme files you need to search for `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title` hook, or to look in the *"woocommerce"* folder inside your theme for the template file `content-product.php` to see if there are some related changes... **Then, if you don't find the right way, you will search and ask in your theme author's support pages.**

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways of doing this - with hooks, or by overriding the WooCommerce template file in your Child theme. First, let's find the code.

The file you're looking for is in the WooCommerce plugin:

```
templates/content-product.php
```

Line 5 of this file says:

```
 This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/content-product.php.
```

Let's look at the file override first.

**Method 1 - File Override**

Copy `templates/content-product.php` from the WooCommerce plugin to `woocommerce/content-product.php` inside your Child theme. This file is now overriding the template in the plugin. We make our desired edits to this new file.

The title in the default `content-product.php` template file is outputted like this:

```
echo '<h2 class="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
```

which is defined in the WooCommerce file `includes/wc-template-functions.php`.

If you search for woocommerce_template_loop_product_title(), you will see the function defined:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title' ) ) {

    /**
     * Show the product title in the product loop. By default this is an H2.
     */
    function woocommerce_template_loop_product_title() {
        echo '<h2 class="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</h2>'; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
    }
}
```

This line of code in the content-product.php file:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );
```

calls the function `woocommerce_template_loop_product_title` which is the function we want to override. So let's comment out that line, and replace it with your code:

```
// do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );
echo '<h6 class="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</h6>';
```

Simple!

**Method 2 - Using Hooks**

The other option is to unhook the remove the `woocommerce_template_loop_product_title` function from the `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title` hook and replace it with our own function. You can do this by adding the following code to your functions.php file:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'soChangeProductsTitle', 10 );
function soChangeProductsTitle() {
    echo '<h6 class="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</h6>';
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your detailed response. However, I'm still having issues getting this to work correctly. Method 1 simply does not work at all and method 2 adds in the H6 but does not remove the original H2, Please see link below for example: https://caseface.ie/shop/.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: I created the overwrite file at httpdocs / wp-content / themes / astra-child / Woocommerce / content-product.php. Is this corrent?