# How to change in loop product title html tag h2 to p in WooCommerce 8

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, product

I'm trying to change the WooCommerce-loop-product__title of the products in the product category from H2 to P, and to H3 in homepage.

I'm using [Martfury](https://themeforest.net/item/martfury-woocommerce-marketplace-wordpress-theme/21273233), a WooCommerce Marketplace WordPress Theme.

I've tried both methods mentioned in [Change woocommerce-loop-product__title From H2 to H6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58651822/change-woocommerce-loop-product-title-from-h2-to-h6) but without success.

- Method 1: It will cause errors on the website.
- Method 2: It only adds a `<p>product title</p>` above the `<h2>product title</h2>`, and the `<h2>product title</h2>` remains unchanged.
- Method 3: I tried modifying the PHP file of WooCommerce to change H2 to P, but it didn't work.

Additionally, when using:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );,
```

`<h2>product title</h2>` still appears.

I hope someone can guide me on how to fix this issue.

Specifically, the WooCommerce-loop-product__title should be H3 on the homepage, while in the product category, the WooCommerce-loop-product__title should be changed to P.

I'm trying to change the WooCommerce-loop-product__title of the products in the product category from H2 to P, and to H3 in homepage.

Comment: As some themes make some changes to WooCommerce templates, function templates, **the Method 2 works in Storefront theme**, but in other themes it will make a duplicated title. **So 1st you need to add in your question, the theme that you are using.** Then in your theme files you need to search for `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title` hook, or to look in the *"woocommerce"* folder inside your theme for the template file `content-product.php` to see if there are some related changes... **Then, if you don't find the right way, you will search and ask in your theme author's support pages.**

Comment: @LoicTheAztec. Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm using this theme: https://themeforest.net/item/martfury-woocommerce-marketplace-wordpress-theme/21273233

Comment: As explained before, and as your theme is a commercial one, this can't be solved here in Stack OverFlow. So you need to search in your theme for `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title` hook, or to look in the "woocommerce" folder inside your theme for the template file `content-product.php` to see if there are some related changes... Then, if you don't find the right way, you will **search** first, and ask in your theme author's support pages.

Comment: Last: If you make changes to WooCommerce templates, you will need first to enable a child theme… Search first, and ask that in your theme author's support pages. Then you will have to copy the desired template file, from "woocommerce" folder in the main parent theme to a folder "woocommerce" in your child theme. If the template doesn't exist in the main theme, then you will copy it from woocommerce plugin "templates" folder to a folder "woocommerce" in your child theme.